# C How to terminate a pointer of char

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I would know if is needed to terminate a pointer of char.
For example:

```
char *pointer;
[...]
pointer[i] = 'a';
[...]
pointer[i] = 'b';
```

At the end I've to add this? ( last i ):

```
pointer[i] = '\0';
```

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer, Yes. It's useful for getting the size and is used in a lot of C functions.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Answer (score 2):

> I would know if is needed to terminate a pointer of char.

You cannot terminate a *pointer*, regardless of the type to which it points.

I suppose you mean to ask whether it is necessary to terminate *the array of `char` to which your pointer points*.  This is an important distinction, because pointers are separate and independent objects from the objects -- if any -- to which they point.  This seems to be lost on many C newbies, and misunderstandings on this contribute to further confusion and mistakes.

The answer, then, is that it depends on how you intend to use the pointer and pointee.  In the likely event that you intend to use the pointee as a C string, whether via the pointer in hand or via some other pointer to the same object, then yes, you need to terminate the array.  All standard library functions for working with strings have undefined behavior if the provided string is not terminated with a null character (`'\0'`).

On the other hand, if you are using the underlying array in some other way -- for example, a known-length array of boolean flags, or a lookup table -- then no, you do not need a terminator at the end.

Comment: The array pointed contains brackets that I've to analyze. I've to put `'\0'`

Answer (score 0):

If your pointer to char is not terminated with\0, it might still print the expected output because following your string is a non-printable character in your memory. This is a really nasty bug though, since it might blow up when you might not expect it. Always terminate a string with '\0'.